# How could I write this if else code checking in a better way?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, conditional-statements

Is this the best way to write this if else code checking?

```
// set the default to Italy if countrySaved is null
if (lang == NULL) {
    lang = @"it";
}

// otherwise set the correct lang based on the country chosed and saved in nsuserdefaults
if ([countrySaved isEqual:@"Brazil"]) {
    lang = @"br";
}

else if ([countrySaved isEqual:@"Spain"]) {
    lang = @"es";
}

else if ([countrySaved isEqual:@"Italy"]) {
    lang = @"it";
}

else if ([countrySaved isEqual:@"United States"]) {
    lang = @"us";
}

else if ([countrySaved isEqual:@"United Kingdom"]) {
    lang = @"uk";
}
```

thanks for any help

Comment: For future reference, questions like this (for working code/optimization) are perfect for the StackExchange site:  [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Store the language IDs in a dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *languageIDs = @{
    @"Brazil" : @"br",
    @"Spain" : @"es",
    @"Italy" : @"it",
    @"United States" : @"us",
    @"United Kingdom" : @"uk"
};
```

Then simply assign `lang` from said dictionary:

```
lang = languageIDs[countrySaved];

if (!lang) {
    lang = languageIDs[@"Italy"];
}
```

Or the shorter way I'd do it using a ternary operator:

```
lang = languageIDs[countrySaved] ?: languageIDs[@"Italy"];
```

---

Also you should probably either load them from a plist file or use `NSString consts` in order to avoid eventually redundant and by that unmaintainable literals scattered all over your code.

Comment: I'm not sure if the ternary operator is truly "better" or just harder to read and unnecessary in this simple case

Comment: @SpathiWankenstein: I actually prefer ternary here. Fair point, though. Modified answer to show both options.

Comment: Loved watching this answer grow +1 And thanks for using the new `@` syntax, which are called...literals? Boxing? I can't recall.

Comment: thanks that's great. is the  @"United Kingdom" : @"uk"
}; ended correctly? it gives me a syntax error.

Comment: @hanumanDev: Good catch. There's a `,` missing after `@"us"`. I'll fix it in a sec.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Dictionary `(key="Country", value="code")` for efficient operations.