# A better approach to coding the a string value test for a NSDictionary object

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How could I write this if else code checking in a better way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663798/how-could-i-write-this-if-else-code-checking-in-a-better-way)

My conditional code here seems repetitive and long. Is there a better approach? I want to test for a string value in a NSDictionary object and then depending upon the value prefix a UILabel with $, £, ¥ currency symbols.

Here's my code (I've just shown 2 examples below, I have more currencies and the code is very long):

```
  if ([[item objectForKey:@"currency"] isEqualToString:@"EUR"]) {

        NSString *priceConvertToStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"€%@", [[item objectForKey:@"price"]stringValue]];

        NSString *priceStringFix = [priceConvertToStr
                                    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(null)" withString:@""];

        priceLabelText.text = priceStringFix;
        [imgView2 addSubview:priceLabelText];

    }

    if ([[item objectForKey:@"currency"] isEqualToString:@"GBP"]) {
        NSString *priceConvertToStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"€%@", [[item objectForKey:@"price"]stringValue]];

        NSString *priceStringFix = [priceConvertToStr
                                    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(null)" withString:@""];

        priceLabelText.text = priceStringFix;
        [imgView2 addSubview:priceLabelText];

    }
    if ([[item objectForKey:@"currency"] isEqualToString:@"USD"]) {
        NSString *priceConvertToStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@", [[item objectForKey:@"price"]stringValue]];

        NSString *priceStringFix = [priceConvertToStr
                                    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(null)" withString:@""];

        priceLabelText.text = priceStringFix;
        [imgView2 addSubview:priceLabelText];

    }
```

thanks so much for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refactor your code to this (possible because essentially 80% of the code within the `if` statements are identical):

```
NSDictionary *currDict = @{
    @"EUR": @"€",
    @"GBP": @"₤",
    @"USD": @"$"
};
NSString *currName = [item objectForKey:@"currency"];
NSString *currency = [currDict objectForKey:currName];

NSString *priceConvertToStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",
    currency,
    [[item objectForKey:@"price"] stringValue]
];
NSString *priceStringFix = [priceConvertToStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(null)" withString:@""];
priceLabelText.text = priceStringFix;
[imgView2 addSubview:priceLabelText];
```

Comment: Which is more or less the answer he got yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/a/14663817/968422

Comment: @Stavash Oh what the holy crap... OP, don't you learn **anything?**